# Why does transform break the dimensions of an element with position:fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I think I asked my question clearly. So imagine this:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.09, .68, 0, .99);
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.box--to-right {
  transform: translateX(300px);
}
.box--to-right:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box--to-right">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

See? The fixed position `:after` pseudo won't be shown although when `.box--to-right` class is applied to the element, then the `:after` pseudo element gets visible with 1 opacity!

So why is that? Shouldn't it work all fine?

And to achieve somehow the similar effect, I know that I can animate `left` instead of using translate transform, but I'm wondering why something like this should happen?

Comment: In our case even if the pseudo element has an absolute position, it won't still work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior appears to be in conformance with the spec:

> [**6 The Transform Rendering
>   Model**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)
>
> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value
>   other than `none` for the transform results in the creation of both a
>   stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a
>   containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

In other words, once you apply transform to an element (as you have done to `.box`), any fixed positioned descendants (like your pseudo-element), start using the transformed element as the containing block, not the viewport.